Draw a string as a binary tree
The string abcdefghijklmno, with length 24-1, can be formatted as such:
       h
      / \
     /   \
    /     \
   d       l
  / \     / \
 b   f   j   n
a c e g i k m o

Each letter should be kept in the same column, but raised up by the right amount to form the above tree structure. Then, slashes (and backslashes) should be added to link each node to the two below. No slashes should be added between the bottom two rows.
Your challenge is to, given a string of lowercase letters of length 2k-1, format it as such. This is code-golf, shortest wins!
Testcases



Input
Output




a
a


bcd
 cb d


hellowo
   l     / \     e   w h l o o


abcdefghijklmno
       h             / \           /   \         /     \       d       l     / \     / \   b   f   j   n a c e g i k m o


thistestcasehasalengththirtyone
               a                             / \                           /   \                         /     \                       /       \                     /         \                   /           \                 /             \               t               h             / \             / \           /   \           /   \         /     \         /     \       s       e       g       y     / \     / \     / \     / \   h   e   a   a   e   h   r   n t i t s c s h s l n t t i t o e




More interesting is to draw a bunch of strings as a prefix tree

Charcoal, 25 bytes
Ｆ²ＦＬθ«Ｊκ⁻¹＆⊕κ±⊕κ¿ι§θκＰ^±ⅉ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
Ｆ²

Loop twice.
ＦＬθ«

Loop over each input character index.
Ｊκ⁻¹＆⊕κ±⊕κ

Jump to that character's position.
¿ι

On the second pass, ...
§θκ

... output the character.
Ｐ^⁻¹ⅉ

On the first pass, draw / and \ diagonals down to the bottom line.
Due to a bug in Charcoal, replacing ⁻¹ with ± results in an extra trailing line of spaces. This bug also then prevents me from drawing the entire diagram one column to the right, otherwise for 17 bytes:
→ＦＳ«Ｊⅈ±＆ⅈ±ⅈＰ^±⊘ⅉι

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
→

Start with the first character in column 1.
ＦＳ«

Loop over each input character.
Ｊⅈ±＆ⅈ±ⅈ

Jump to that character's position.
Ｐ^±⊘ⅉ

Draw / and \ diagonals halfway to the bottom (without moving the cursor).
ι

Output the current character.
(I do have an experimental branch where this version should print correctly with no padding.)

Python 3.8 (pre-release),  158   144   143  142 bytes
-14 bytes by Unrelated String.
-2 bytes by emanresu A.
t=lambda s:(r:=len(s)//2)and[l.center(r-~r)for l in[s[r]]+[f'/{" "*i}\\'for i in range(1,r,2)]]+[*map(' '.join,zip(t(s[:r]),t(s[r+1:])))]or[s]

Try it online!

Very nice! 144 by cutting out one of the list comprehensions and reusing your assignment for base case testing.

-1 with fstrings (edit: I missed unrelatedstring's golf but this still applies)

-1 more

Jelly, 31 28 27 bytes
Jm2BỊḄJ=&ɗⱮJḤṚ|Ɗị"Ø^;;⁶Ʋ€UZ

Try it online!
Yikes... Still feels a little golfable, but it might just be the wrong approach entirely. It seems tantalizingly simple with certain praclang tools, but with so much to juggle, it comes out suprisingly clunky in Jelly!
Returns a list of lines.
Jm2BỊḄJ=&ɗⱮJḤṚ|Ɗ    Build the tree:
Jm2                 For every [1, 3 .. length],
   B                take its arbitrary-length binary representation
     Ḅ              and convert back from binary
    Ị               with all bits set to 1.
Jm2BỊḄ              This creates a bitmask for the period of that column.
         ɗⱮJ        For each [1 .. length],
       =&           is its bitwise AND with each mask equal to
      J             the 1-index of that mask?
            ḤṚ      Double and reverse the comparisons
              |Ɗ    and bitwise OR with the original comparisons.

ị"Ø^;;⁶Ʋ€UZ    Format the tree:
ị              Modular 1-index each row into
 "     Ʋ€      the corresponding character
  Ø^;          appended to "/\"
     ;⁶        with a space appended.
         U     Reverse each row
          Z    and transpose.


JavaScript (Node.js), 105 bytes
s=>(g=i=>s[i++*2]?g(i)+s.map(c=>(++j&-j)^i?(x=j&g-1)-i?x+i^g?' ':'\\':'/':(g=2*i,c),j=0).join``+`
`:'')``

Try it online!
Actually I don't understand ...

Haskell, 210,196,193,192 bytes
unlines.g
g s|l<-div(length s)2,k<-div l 2=1&s>>i[s!!l](2*l+1)l:zipWith((.(' ':)).(++))(k&map(i"/"l.(l-))[1..]++g(l&s))(k&map(i"\\"l)[0..]++g(drop(l+1)s))
(&)=take
i[c]n p=n&(p&w++c:w)
w=' ':w

-3 bytes thanks to Unrelated String
Try it online!

193

Perl 5, 152 bytes
sub{map$p=$_||$p=~s| /|/ |gr=~s|\\ ?| \\|gr=~s| \w ?|/ \\|gr,map{$"x($n/2).join($"x$n,@_[grep$_+1==($_^$n),0..$#_]),(0)x(($n>>=1)/2)}0..1.44*log($n=@_)}

Try it online!
